# How to receive a notification when a user (A) )follows user (B) using firebase cloud functions and Flutter

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new using firebase functions, I already set up the environment and deploy a different function that works fine, however, I would like to know how to implement a function that allows users to receive a notification when someone starts following them(notification when new id is added the follower's collection).

This is the database that gets an Id when the user(A) follows the user (B), any user has their own id so when a user follows another user, the id from the user (A) is saved into the user (B) id(`followers collection`). so, I need a function that sends a notification to the user(B) the one that gets a new follower.

**See below the structure**

[image]

The method that creates the user profile with the follow or unfollow button

```
  _buildUserProfile() {
    double height = responsive.height(context);
    double width = responsive.width(context);
    String comment = widget.reviews.comments;
    int reviews = _posts.length;
    int followersNew = _followerCount;
    int likeCount = widget.reviews.likeCount;
    int point = reviews * 10;
    int point2 = followersNew * 30;
    int point3 = likeCount * 20;
    int totalPoints = point + point2 + point3;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                boxShadow: shadowList,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              height: height / 2,
              width: width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height / 50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height / 50,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height / 130,
        ),
        _productImage(),
        SizedBox(
          height: height / 130,
        ),
        MessageFollowUnfollowEditButton(
          followOrUnfollow: _followOrUnfollow,
          isFollowing: _isFollowing,
          user: widget.user,
          reviewId: widget.authorId,
          imageUrl: widget.userImage,
          reviews: widget.reviews,
          currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
          isTrue: widget.isTrue == true ? true : false,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width / 22, 5.0, width / 22, 0.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            responsive.width(context) / 42),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.white,
                            Colors.white,
                          ],
                        ),
                        boxShadow: shadowList,
                      ),
                      //aqui
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(width / 22),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  _posts.length.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: width / 22,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Opiniones',
                                  style: kjosefin,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  _followerCount.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: width / 22,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Seguidores',
                                  style: kjosefin,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.control_point,
                                      size: width / 20,
                                      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      totalPoints.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: width / 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Puntaje',
                                  style:
                                      kjosefin.copyWith(fontSize: height / 70),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite,
                                      size: width / 20,
                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${widget.reviews.likeCount.toString()}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: width / 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Likes',
                                  style: kjosefin,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height / 130,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: width / 1.1,
                      height: height / 8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: shadowList,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(height / 70),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(height / 70),
                          child: Text(
                            '"$comment"',
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            maxLines: 9,
                            style: kjosefin.copyWith(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**notifications**

```
class FollowerNotification extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'chat_list';
  final String currentUserId;
  final String peerId;
  final User user;
  FollowerNotification({Key key, this.currentUserId, this.peerId, this.user})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() =>
      FollowerNotificationState(currentUserId: currentUserId);
}

class FollowerNotificationState extends State<FollowerNotification> {
  FollowerNotificationState({Key key, @required this.currentUserId});

  final String currentUserId;
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
    configLocalNotification();
  }

  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage: $message');
        Platform.isAndroid
            ? showNotification(message['notification'])
            : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onResume: $message');
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onLaunch: $message');
        return;
      },
    );

    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then(
      (token) {
        print('token: $token');
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(widget.currentUserId)
            .updateData({'pushToken': token});
      },
    ).catchError(
      (err) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
      },
    );
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'com.dfa.flutterchatdemo'
          : 'com.duytq.flutterchatdemo',
      'Flutter chat demo',
      'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);
    print(message['body'].toString());
    print(json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message['title'].toString(),
        message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
```

**Code that I have in the index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()


exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
 .document('messages/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
 .onCreate((snap, context) => {
   console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

   const doc = snap.data()
   console.log(doc)

   const idFrom = doc.idFrom
   const idTo = doc.idTo
   const contentMessage = doc.content

   // Get push token user to (receive)
   admin
     .firestore()
     .collection('users')
     .where('id', '==', idTo)
     .get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
       querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
         console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().nickname}`)
         if (userTo.data().pushToken && userTo.data().chattingWith !== idFrom) {
           // Get info user from (sent)
           admin
             .firestore()
             .collection('users')
             .where('id', '==', idFrom)
             .get()
             .then(querySnapshot2 => {
               querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                 console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().nickname}`)
                 const payload = {
                   notification: {
                     title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().nickname}"`,
                     body: contentMessage,
                     badge: '1',
                     sound: 'default'
                   }
                 }
                 // Let push to the target device
                 admin
                   .messaging()
                   .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload)
                   .then(response => {
                     console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
                   })
                   .catch(error => {
                     console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                   })
               })
             })
         } else {
           console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
         }
       })
     })
   return null
 })
```

Comment: Hello, what I've you already tried?? can you share some code?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: Your Cloud Function is a background triggered one and you chain several calls to async methods. So you must return the chain of all the promises returned by these methods, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to terminate a Cloud Function when all the asynchronous work is completed, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). In the case of a background triggered Cloud Function (e.g. Cloud Firestore function `onCreate` trigger) you must return the chain of promises returned by the asynchronous method calls.

In your case, not only you don't return the promise returned by `get()` but you have a `return null;` at the end that may indicate to the Cloud Function platform that it can clean up your function before the asynchronous work is completed.

The following should do the trick (untested). Note that I make the assumption that there is only one doc corresponding to `where('id', '==', idTo)` as well as only one doc corresponding to `where('id', '==', idFrom)`.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('messages/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const doc = snap.data()
        console.log(doc)

        const idFrom = doc.idFrom
        const idTo = doc.idTo
        const contentMessage = doc.content

        // Get push token user to (receive)
        return admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .where('id', '==', idTo)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const userTo = querySnapshot.docs[0];
                console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().nickname}`)
                if (userTo.data().pushToken && userTo.data().chattingWith !== idFrom) {
                    // Get info user from (sent)
                    return admin
                        .firestore()
                        .collection('users')
                        .where('id', '==', idFrom)
                        .get();
                } else {
                    console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
                    throw new Error('Can not find pushToken target user');
                }
            })
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const userFrom = querySnapshot.docs[0];
                console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().nickname}`)
                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().nickname}"`,
                        body: contentMessage,
                        badge: '1',
                        sound: 'default'
                    }
                }
                // Let push to the target device
                return admin
                    .messaging()
                    .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload);
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                return null;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                return null;
            });

    });
```